# Can we approximate distribution of $\log_2\frac{X}{YZ}$ as Gaussian distribution when $X,Y,Z$ follows a beta distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

In paper [(Orre 2000)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222562806_Bayesian_neural_networks_with_confidence_estimation_applied_to_data_mining), the author approximates distribution of $\log_2\frac{X}{YZ}$ as Gaussian distribution when
$$
X\sim Beta(a_1,a_2)\\
Y\sim Beta(b_1,b_2)\\
Z\sim Beta(c_1,c_2)
$$
where $a_i,b_i,c_i$ are all positive integers. $X,Y,Z$ are assumed to be independent.

The author didn't write the proof of Gaussian approximation. However, using Monte Carlo Simulation, I could find out that the density plot is approximately the normal density plot. I'm just curious if it can be proved in a theoretical way when hyperparameters are all positive integers and variables are independent.

Below is an example of Monte Carlo simulation

```
a1 <- 4
a2 <- 5
b1 <- 10
b2 <- 20
c1 <- 5
c2 <- 10
x <- rbeta(10000,a1,a2)
y <- rbeta(10000,b1,b2)
z <- rbeta(10000,c1,c2)

plot(density(log2(x/(y*z))))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks less symmetric (and so less normal) if you use $a_1=1, a_2=10$ and $b_1=30, b_2=1$ and $c_1=15, c_2=1$

Comment: But a beta distributed random variable with both parameters large (they do not have to be close to each other) is not far from normally distributed; nor is its logarithm.  Here you are looking at  $\log_2(x)-\log_2(y)-\log_2(z)$ so essentially the sum of three almost-normally distributed random variables and combining the three takes this even closer

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, the curve is less normal for some specified values. In proving this, my perspective is to first prove that $log_2(x)$ can be approximated by normal distribution using Laplace's method under some conditions and second use convolutions to prove that sum of random variables is approximately normal. But I'm not sure if it makes sense.